# Want just numeric keypad but getting an alphabetical keypad also

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want only numeric keypad with a "Done" key to appear for my following code so that I can type a normal integer or a decimal number. But instead I'm getting a numeric keypad with a "Next" key. when this "Next" key is pressed, it moves to an alphabetical keypad which i don't want. I want it to directly move to the activity screen after the value is inserted and the Next or Done key is pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/black">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/select_from"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" 
            android:layout_weight="1">  
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:entries="@array/angle_List"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/select_to"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TextView>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:entries="@array/angle_List"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/convert" 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Convert">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clearVal"
            android:text="@string/clear">
        </Button>   
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

thanks in advance

UPDATE-

I got my problem solved by using

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

in my  tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        ((EditText)v).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        }
    });
```